# How to rephrase the below query without subquery

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, subquery, correlated-subquery

[image]

Here is the table :
To get all columns from 'orders' and 'despatch' table after joining, with the following condition -

1. 'ord_date' should be largest(maximum) from the 'orders' table,
2. largest (maximum) 'ord_date' should be equal to the 'ord_date' of ' orders' table,
3. 'agent_code' of 'orders' table should be equal to the 'agent_code' of 'despatch' table for joining,

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN despatch 
ON orders.agent_code = despatch.agent_code 
WHERE orders.ord_date=(
SELECT MAX(ord_date) FROM orders where orders.agent_code = 'A004');
```

Is there any way to rephrase the query without subquery

```
orders.ord_date=(
    SELECT MAX(ord_date) FROM orders where orders.agent_code = 'A004');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use MAX in your select:

```
SELECT MAX (ord_date), ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM orders 
LEFT JOIN despatch ON orders.agent_code = despatch.agent_code 
GROUP BY ColA, ColB, ColC
```

Comment: sorry I have missed one thing here have a where condition for max date  both of them given different result `WHERE orders.ord_date=(
SELECT MAX(ord_date) FROM orders where orders.agent_code = 'A004'`